# Edit Raster Function not working in MDCS

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, mosaic-dataset

I have a python script tool that calls a MDCS. For some reason the edit raster function does not work anymore. I can apply it with the GUI tool and it works. I have tested with other TIFs. It actually worked before, but I cannot remember what I have changed. However, it is likely to be something in the xml-file, because it also did not work with an older version of my python script.

extract from config file:

```
<Command>CM+SP+SE+AR+CV+CV+IG+ClipFootprints+SE+ERF+ERF+BB</Command>
...
<EditRasterFunction>
        <edit_mosaic_dataset_item>EDIT_MOSAIC_DATASET</edit_mosaic_dataset_item>
        <edit_options>INSERT</edit_options>
        <function_chain_definition>DTK-$layer$ormap_PQS1.0.rft.xml</function_chain_definition>
        <location_function_name>Mosaic Function</location_function_name>
</EditRasterFunction>
```

The file "DTK-colormap_PQS1.0.rft.xml" is in the folder RasterFunctionTemplates, the variable layer is defenetely set to col. Does it maybe have to do with the order of the commands? I tried inserting the to ERF just after Add Rasters, did not help.

python:

```
 param_s = ["x", f"-i:{config}", f"-p:{workspace_pfad}$workspace", f"-p:{bundesland}$land", f"-p:{srs}$srs", f"-p:{cellsize}$cellsize",
               f"-p:{data_pfad}$dataPath", f"-p:{utm}$utm", f"-p:{massstab}$massstab", "-p:8_BIT_UNSIGNED$pixeltype", f"-p:{datum}$datum", "-p:col$layer"]
 
 MDCS.main(len(param_s), param_s)
```